# ansible-pull ignore group_vars vault

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

How do I ignore the `group_vars` vault file when running ansible-pull?

My repository (among other stuff) does machine init, joining the domain and software updates. I would like the software part to be handled by ansible-pull. No passwords are required for this, and no vault is necessary.

Unfortunately, initial machine setup after a fresh install does require some passwords which are set in `group_vars/all.yml` and is encrypted by vault. Whenever I run the `ansible-pull` command I run into vault decryption issues as there is no password provided.

Any advice on how to overcome this?

Comment: I'd say it sounds like you need to split your repo into two repos.

Comment: Thanks Chicks. Though I prefer to keep everything together. I know I could work with submodules in git, but it seems such a hassle...

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I just got rid of the group_vars all together.
I specified a new role that includes several other roles with 'include_role:' and added the vars directly to those roles with inline-vault variables:

```
- name: include ipaclient
  include_role:
    name: ipaclient
  vars:
    my_user: user
    my_password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          123456123456123456123456123456132456...
```